# Is there a way to force Google Photos to create a story of a certain time range?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I had someone visiting me for 16 days in another country. We travelled a lot, took pictures, videos. It would be amazing to have a Story made by Google Photos on Google+ out of this time range. I couldn't find a function of Google Photos to create a new story.

Is it just Google who guesses what time range to analyse and create a story? Are there any known triggers to create a story?

Story would make more sense than an autoawesome movie this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Google Photos you can currently create Stories only from the Google Photos app on phone or tablet.

Basically you click on the `+` icon, choose "Story" and then select the photos, see:

https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en&rd=2

See how the app looks like on a smartphone:

[image]

Comment: I cannot see that and the link is not showing it. I tried to click it  on my two devices but there is no plus button in Google photos

Comment: you probably don't have yet the last version of the application. See here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en check the screenshots, does you application look like that? if you check within the pictures, there is one that shows the `+` button.

Comment: added screenshot to the answer got from the play store

Comment: I just received an update. The new app is amazing, however they removed a lot of functionality when creating and editing an autoawesome movie, which is very sad, since now it is impossible to fine tune the good details as it was before.

Answer (score -1):

> Stories are automatically created and you’ll be notified when one is made for you.

[Make a story](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6029803)